# Register Function In API Fetch ES6

Tags: javascript, html, forms, authentication

I have a popup modal with my register function. The problem is that it closes the popup after i clicked the register button despite the fields are not yet completely filled out or there are errors. I already put "required" in input element and it does nothing. Is there something wrong in my code. I trying to fetch api register from a website.

```js
function registerUser(event){

    console.log(event)

    event.preventDefault();

 console.log(document.forms[0].checkValidity());
    fetch('http://sample_website.com/api/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            given_name: document.getElementById("given_name").value,
            last_name: document.getElementById("last_name").value,
            email: document.getElementById("email").value,
            password: document.getElementById("password").value,
            password_confirmation: document.getElementById("confirm_password").value
        })
    })
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data =>  { 
        console.log(data);
        if(data.response){
            alert("Successfully Registered"); 
        } else{
            alert("Sorry, email has already been taken.");
        } 
    })
    .catch((err) => {
         alert ("This is a warning message!");
        console.error(err);
    })

   
}

 window.onload = function() {
  document.forms[0]
  .addEventListener("submit", registerUser)
}
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="register" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title text-info" id="myModalLabel">Register Now</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">    
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label>Given Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="given_name" name="given_name" class = "form-control" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="last_name" name="lname" class = "form-control" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class = "form-control" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class = "form-control" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "form-group">
                        <label>Confirm Password</label> 
                        <input type="password" id="confirm_password" name="c_password" class = "form-control" required/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ata-dismiss = "modal" ><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Register</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perhaps it's because `registerUser` doesn't return anything, so any code calling it does not know when it is "done" - show how registerUser is being used, because nothing in that function closes any popup, so clearly your problem exists elsewhere

Comment: @JaromandaX. It does. Wait i'll put the input elements

Comment: "it does" ... *what is `it` and what does `it` do?* (say it like Arnie in Kindergarten Cop for maximum effect) Are you saying `registerUser` returns something? yes, it returns `undefined` ... you say *i'll put the input elements* - how does that help you show how the popup is shown and how it is closed? None of the code you've presented does any of that, which is probably quite important to your question

Comment: Oh, right, so registerUser is called from a click event, I take it `data-dismiss="modal"` means that some code elsewhere is also closing the modal when you click this button - and that's your problem

Comment: @JaromandaX. Thanks for the advice. So onclick is  not used now? onclick is not good to use, right?

Answer (score 1):

`fetch()` and JavaScript in general is not related to the issue described at Question.

The issue is that at the HTML at Question the `<form>` is valid.

Thus the `<form>` is submitted at `click` at `<button>` element.

You have set the `value` attribute to a valid string which is not empty. There are no `pattern` attributes at `<input>` elements to set `RegExp` validity pattern to a value other than existing `.value` property.

Substitute `placeholder` for `value` attribute or include `pattern` attribute to reflect that default `value` should not be valid.

```html
<script>
function registerUser() {
  console.log(document.forms[0].checkValidity())
}
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="register" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form>
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title text-info" id="myModalLabel">Register Now</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Given Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="given_name" name="given_name" placeholder="Joseph" class="form-control" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="last_name" name="lname" placeholder="Book" class="form-control" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="123@gmail.com" class="form-control" required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="123" class="form-control"  required/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="confirm_password" name="c_password" placeholder="123" class="form-control" required/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button onclick="registerUser();" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Register</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @Joseph Note that when the HTML `<form>` is properly filled the `<form>` will still be submitted, reloading the `document`, as you have not prevented the default action of `form` submission. Use `.addEventListener()` or `onsubmit` to catch the submit event, call `event.preventDefault()` then call `fetch()`

Comment: So you say, onclick is not used commonly used now? Can you help me edit my code using .addeventListener or onsubmit and event.preventDefault(). Please and thank you.

Comment: @Joseph You can remove attribute event handler at HTML, use `onsubmit` or `.addEventListener()` for ability to call `event.preventDefault()` at event handler `function registerUser(event) {event.preventDefault();// do fetch stuff}; document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", registerUser)` https://jsfiddle.net/uw79wwg3/

Comment: @Joseph The previously linked jsfiddle calls `.text()`, converted `FormData` instance key, value pairs to an object then passed to `JSON.stringify()` then called `.json()` https://jsfiddle.net/uw79wwg3/1/. All of which can be substituted for your own code, or simply pass `<form>` to `FormData()` and set `FormData` instance at `body`. The jsfiddle is to demonstrate that the `event` default action is prevented and the data is `POST`ed at `fetch()` call, see `console`

Comment: Can you check my snippet above. It doesn't alert error or successful registered. Thank you

Comment: What is `data.response`?

Comment: the value of data from the api. You can edit my snippet if my code is bad.

Comment: @Joseph Remove `onsubmit="registerUser();"`. Do other `<form>` elements exist in `document`?

Comment: guest271314. Can you edit snippet please? if it's ok with you.

Comment: You should be able to edit the code. `window.onload = function() {
  document.forms[0]
  .addEventListener("submit", registerUser)
}` should be outside of `registerUser` function block as well as removing event attribute at `<form>` element, as described at previous comment.

Comment: Can you check it again? and edit my snippet? maybe you can use formData if its recommended. Thank you

Comment: You still have not removed `onsubmit="registerUser();"` from `<form onsubmit="registerUser();">`

Comment: Can you check it again?

Comment: The most recent version should return expected result

Comment: After i submit register form, it still has problem. It says "Sorry, email has already been taken" even if the email is not previously registered.

Comment: That is a server issue, not related to original Question

Comment: I don't think so. Maybe you can fix above the if else statement. Please?

Comment: @Joseph Fix to what? What is `data.response` and what is expected result?

Comment: data.response is the response from the api. If it registered successfully, it should response this {
    "message": "Registration successful",
    "response": true
}
  if its not successful, {
    "message": "Validation failed",
    "errors": {
    "email": [
        "The email must be a valid email address."
        ]
    },
    "response": false
}

Comment: You can remove the "if else" if you have a better way to fix it.

Comment: @Joseph Not sure what you are trying to "fix" at JavaScript?

Comment: If email has been previously registered it should alert that email has already been registered. If not, then it should alert successfully registered.

Comment: @Joseph The response is from server. Server response  determines whether `if` or `else` block is reached. Do you mean that `data.response` is `true` and `else` block is still reached?

Comment: When you try `data.response` is `false` though `if` statement is reached?

Comment: I dont get what you mean. But i mean is if "if" statement is reached it should reply successful registered. And else if email has already been registered

Comment: I got it already. I didn't use your code. But thanks a lot for your effort. Appreciated it